# Ошибка выгрузки CSV в PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

Создал таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
date    date,
time    time,
val3    float,
val4    float);
```

Пытаюсь в нее выгрузить CSV следующей командой:
    copy data from 'G:\test\1.txt' DELIMETERS ' ' CSV;

```
Сам сам файл такой:
date time val3 val4 
2012.08.10 06:53:18 695.417 773.29
```

При попытке выполнить команду получаю ошибку:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "date"
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Или убрать первую строку из файла или добавить параметр HEADER в команду COPY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

даты через дефис

2012-08-10

Comment: А как быть, если у меня они через точку?
Следующая команда не помогает. http://postimg.org/image/51n25xr0z/

Comment: Знак равенства пропустили

     set datestyle="German, YMD";